# mysql_real_escape_string not showing error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-real-escape-string

I am moving my application from Mysql extension to PHP PDO. 
I am facing a strange problem. 
In my development environment, I have both db server [MySQL] and web server are in single system where as in testing environment web and db servers are in different system.

The following test code runs perfectly in dev environment and fails in test environment.

```
    require "class.DB.php" ;

    class DbMaster extends DB
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->Host     = "192.168.1.00";
            $this->Database = 'test_database';
            $this->User     = "root";
            $this->Password = "12345";
        }
    }

    // Creates the instance
    $db = new DbMaster();

    $table = mysql_real_escape_string('persons');
    $result_array = $db->query("SELECT Id, Age FROM $table WHERE Id >= :Id", array("Id" => 1));

    foreach ($result_array as $rec)
    {
        echo '<br>'.$rec["Id"].' -> '.$rec['Age'];

    }
```

In dev, mysql_real_escape_string should fail, because there is no mysql_connect().

But, mysql_real_escape_string works when there is a mysql server running locally. To test this in dev environment I stopped the local mysql and connected to remote database. Then I got the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established
```

So with my existing development setup [both web and db server together], I am not able to see the PDO related errors.

Any way to resolve this problem.

Comment: See that red rectangle in the [mysql_real_escape_string docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)? Please, follow the warning and use  [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [PDO escaping - quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php):

Comment: Why do you need to escape the table name? Does it (or will it) come from user input?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but as you are using prepared statements you dont need to manually sanitize data like that - thats one of the main reasons for using the newer database functions

Comment: I agree.. I don't need sanitizing. As I mentioned in the first line. "I am moving my application from mysql to PDO." 
I am supposed to get an error if any mysql_real_escape_string still used. OR any of the query is not converted to PDO. But I am not getting the error. That is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` tries to open a connection to a server with `mysql_connect()` if no connection exist. The default values for `mysql_connect()` are "localhost" and "root" without a password.

If you have the root account without a password in your development environment (which is a pretty common setup) this will work without problem, since a connection can be esteblished.

On the live environment on the other hand, the root user hopefully has a password set, so this call will fail.

In this case `mysql_real_escape_string()` will return `false` instead of your escaped value.

The solution: Use the mysqli or PDO equivalent of the function. Or open an additional connection using `mysql_connect()` with valid credentials for the time being so `mysql_real_escape_string()` can use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just stopped the mysql in the development environment. That worked fine..